# WPF DataGrid ItemsSource memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, memory-leaks, datagrid

I don't know why but when I define the ItemsSource of my DataGrid, it creates some memory leak.

This is the xaml code of my DataGrid :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" ClipboardCopyMode="ExcludeHeader" Margin="20,250,20,20" SelectionUnit="Cell" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDataGrid}" SelectionMode="Single"/>
```

And this is the code behind where I define the ItemsSource :

```
cmd = New SqlCommand With {
    .CommandText = strsql,
    .Connection = DBConn.ADONETconn
    }
da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
dt = New DataTable("RECH")
da.Fill(dt)
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView
```

As you can see from the diagnostic tool, I have some memory leak somewhere.
[image]

I know it's caused by the line `DataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView` because if I comment it, the memory leak doesn't occur.

I've downloaded JetBrains dotMemory to see what's going on.
As you can see bellow, it tells me that it's caused by DataGridRow.
[image]

I don’t understand why this happens. The data is correct in the DataTable.
[image]

If you have any clues, please share them with me

Comment: Can you trace the retention paths? It's possible with JetBrains Profiler.

Comment: The call tree helped me to find the problem. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like the `DataView` has a Dispose method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found ! Actually it came from the fact that my DataGrid was in a StackPanel. And I still don’t know why but it was a problem.

Comment: how did you find the issue? Was it with dotMemory, or just trial and error?

Comment: DotMemory let me know that the problem came from the DatagridRow. Then I made some attempts to fix the problem. I tried to change the SQL query of my DataGrid to see if the problem didn’t come from there but unfortunately I still had the problem. So I thought maybe the problem was the UI (XAML). At that time I made a very simple page with the minimum of controls to isolate the problem. I ended up finding that the problem was that my DataGrid was in a stackpanel. I replaced the StackPanel with a Grid and it worked

Comment: I face a same issue, but for my case it is inside the Grid already, so after some few days research, I found out the `EnableRowVirtualization='True'` did help, because I have a large dataset to display